# The requested URL /_Incapsula_Resource was not found on this server

Tags: web-scraping, http-status-code-404

While using [simple HTML dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to get some data from a site , I got this   error

```
 Not Found
 The requested URL /_Incapsula_Resource was not found on this server.
```

as I have used this library many times but this happened for the first time and the URL works well when pasted in the browser.
Kindly can you suggest me the solution? Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and the answer below is not relevant. URL works in browser but not in nodejs Request or Postman.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get HTTP status code:

```
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

If 404, it means the request URL cannot be found.

Note: remember to issue this line before curl_close($ch);